# Connecting 2 different databases doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

First of all, I already know about how mysql_connect are not advisable to use but i have no time to learn the PDO commands and once I solve this first, i will change it to PDO. But now, im still having trouble merging two codes with different database connection on each file.

```
<?php



    $dbh1 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
    $dbh2 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', true); 

    mysql_select_db('invoices', $dbh1);
    mysql_select_db('hmis', $dbh2);

    $id = '17';

    /////

      if ($id) {
    echo "<h1>Edit Medical Records # : $id</h1>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo " <h1>Medical Records</h1>";
    }


    if($submit)
    {
    //-------------------check user name-----------------------------------------------------
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $select = "select first_name from patient where last_name = '".$last_name."';";
    $query = mysql_query($select,$dbh1) or die ("Mysql error! It was: ".mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($rows != 0)
    {

      echo ("<script language=javascript>alert ('Sorry! $first_name is already taken!')</script>");
      echo ("<script language=javascript>document.location.href = 'editclient.php'</script>");

    exit;
    }
    if($name == "admin"){
      echo ("<script language=javascript>alert ('Sorry! $first_name is not a good thing to do!')</script>");
      echo ("<script language=javascript>document.location.href = 'editclient.php'</script>");
    exit;

    }
    //-----------------------------------end check-------------------------------------------
    $sql = "INSERT INTO patient (`first_name`, `last_name`,`country`, `address`, `gender`, `telno`, `occ`, `spo`, `occ2`,`cp`, `tel2`, `reff`, `all`, `ill`, `mat`, `frat`, `datetime`, `vs`,`ppe`, `ffup`)
    VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$country','$address','$gender','$telno','$occ','$spo','$occ2', '$cp','$tel2','$reff','$all','$ill','$mat','$frat','$datetime','$vs','$ppe','$ffup')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$dbh1);
    //echo ("<script language=javascript>document.location.href = 'editclient.php?id=$id&message=Patient $id has been Created!'</script>");
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Succesfully Updated')
        window.location.href='sample4.php';
        </SCRIPT>");

    }
    else if($update)
    {

    $sql = "UPDATE patient set first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',
    country='$country',address='$address',gender='$gender',telno='$telno',
    occ='$occ',spo='$spo',occ2='$occ2', cp='$cp', tel2='$tel2',reff='$reff', ill='$ill', mat='$mat', frat='$frat', datetime='$datetime', vs='$vs', ppe='$ppe' ,ffup='$ffup'
    WHERE clientid=$id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql ,$dbh1);
    //echo ("<script language=javascript>document.location.href = 'editclient.php?id=$id&message=Client $id has been Updated!'</script>");
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Succesfully Updated')
        window.location.href='sample4.php';
        </SCRIPT>");


    }
    else if($id)
    {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE clientid=$id",$dbh1);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    ?>
    </p>
    <br><font color=red size=4><?php if (isset($_GET['message'])) { echo ' - '.$_GET['message']; } ?></font><BR>
    <?

    //-------------NEXT PREVIOUS----------------------------------------------------------------------

    $sql ="SELECT * FROM patient WHERE clientid < '$id' ORDER by clientid DESC LIMIT 1";

    $resultp = mysql_query($sql ,$dbh1);
    $previousrows = mysql_num_rows($resultp);
    while ($prerow = mysql_fetch_array($resultp)) {
    $prev=$prerow['clientid'];
    }
    //echo $prev;

    $sql2 ="SELECT clientid FROM patient WHERE clientid > '$id' ORDER by clientid ASC LIMIT 1";

    $resultn = mysql_query($sql2,$dbh1);
    $nextrows = mysql_num_rows($resultn);
    while ($nextrow = mysql_fetch_array($resultn)) {
    $next=$nextrow['clientid'];
    }
    //echo $next;
    if ($previousrows == "") {
    echo "";
    }else{
    echo "<B><a href=$PHP_SELF?id=$prev>$prev <- Prev</a> | ";
    }
    echo "<font size=6><B>$id</B></font>";
    if ($nextrows == "") {
    echo "";
    }else{
    echo "<b> | <a href=$PHP_SELF?id=$next > Next -> $next</a></b>";
    }
    //-----------------end next prev-----------------------------------------------------
    ?><br><br>
    <?php include("inc/nav.inc");?>
    <form name="form2a" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF?>">
       <table width="760" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="50%" colspan="2">
    Edit Patient Information:</td>
          <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="10" rowspan="20">
    &nbsp;</td>
          <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="50%">
    Procedures:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row["clientid"]?>">
    First name:<br>
    </td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    &nbsp;<input type="text" size="20" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row["first_name"]?>" ></td>
          <td valign="top" width="10%" rowspan="13">




          <!-- edit include inv -->

          <?php //include ('testinclude.php'); ?>

            <!-- END -->




          </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right">
    Last Name:
    </td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    &nbsp;<input type="text" name="last_name" size="20" value="<?php echo $row["last_name"]?>"></td>
       </tr>


       <tr> 
        <td valign="top" align="right"> Gender:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left"><select name="gender">
          <option value="Male">Male</option>
          <option value="Female">Female</option> </select> 
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td valign="top" align="right">  Country:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
          <select name="country" >
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>

    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
    <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
            <option value="China">China</option>
            <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>


    <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
    <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar (Burma)</option>
    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
    <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
    <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
    <option value="UAE">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>

        </select> 

        </tr>

            <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right">
    Tel. no.:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="telno" placeholder="###-####" value="<?php echo $row["telno"]?>"></td></tr>
     <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right">
    Occupation:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="occ" value="<?php echo $row["occ"]?>"></td></tr>
     <tr>
          <td align="right">
    Spouse:</td>
          <td >
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="spo" value="<?php echo $row["spo"]?>"></td></tr><tr>
      <td align="right">
    Occupation:</td>
          <td >
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="occ2" value="<?php echo $row["occ2"]?>"></td></tr>



     <tr>
          <td align="right" width="20">
    Contact Person(in case of emergency):</td>
          <td >
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="cp" value="<?php echo $row["cp"]?>"></td></tr><tr>
      <td align="right">
    Tel. no:</td>
          <td >
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="tel2" value="<?php echo $row["tel2"]?>"></td></tr>

        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Address:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $row["address"]?>" size="31"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Reffered By:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="reff" value="<?php echo $row["reff"]?>" size="31" ></td>
          </tr>

              <tr>
          <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="50%" colspan="2">
    Past Medical History:</td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Allergy:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="all" value="<?php echo $row["all"]?>" size="31"></td>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Previous illness:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="ill" value="<?php echo $row["ill"]?>" size="31"></td>
          </tr>

        <tr>
         <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="50%" colspan="2">
    <b><font size="4">
    Heredo-Familial Diseases:</font></b></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Maternal:
         </td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="mat" value="<?php echo $row["mat"]?>" size="20"></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Fraternal:
         </td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="frat" value="<?php echo $row["frat"]?>" size="20"></td>
          </tr>

    <tr>
         <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="50%" colspan="2">
    <b><font size="4">
    Examination:</font></b></td>
          </tr>   
    <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Date / Time:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="datetime" value="<?php echo $row["datetime"]?>" size="31"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Vital Signs:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="vs" value="<?php echo $row["vs"]?>" size="31"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td align="center" nowrap>
    Complain PPE Findings:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="ppe" value="<?php echo $row["ppe"]?>" size="31"></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
          <td align="center" nowrap>
    Plan / Management / FF-UP</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="ffup" value="<?php echo $row["ffup"]?>" size="31"></td>
          </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class=topHeadrow1 valign="middle" width="100%" colspan="4">
    <p align="center"><input class="form-button" type="Submit" name="update" value="Update Information"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" width="100%" colspan="4">
    <br>
    </td>
        </tr>
      </table>


      </form>

    <?
    }
    else
    {
    //----------------------------begin add client--------------------------------------------------------
    ?>
    <br><font color=red size=4><?php if (isset($_GET['message'])) { echo ' - '.$_GET['message']; } ?></font><BR>

    <form name="form2b" method="post" action="editclient.php" onSubmit="return checkPw(this)">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="topHeadrow5" valign="top" width="100%" colspan="5">
    <b><font size="4">Patient Information:</font></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right">
    First Name:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="first_name" ></td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right">
    Last Name:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" size="20"></td></tr>
        <tr> 
        <td valign="top" align="right"> Gender:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left"><select name="gender">
          <option value="Male">Male</option>
          <option value="Female">Female</option> </select> 
               </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td valign="top" align="right">Country:</td>
      <td valign="top" align="left">
          <select name="country" >
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>

    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
    <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
            <option value="China">China</option>
            <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>


    <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
    <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar (Burma)</option>
    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
    <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
    <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
    <option value="UAE">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>

        </select> 

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right">
    Tel. no.:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="telno" placeholder="###-####"></td></tr>
     <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right">
    Occupation:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="occ" ></td></tr>
     <tr>
          <td align="right">
    Spouse:</td>
          <td >
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="spo" ></td>
      <td align="right">
    Occupation:</td>
          <td >
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="occ2" ></td></tr>



     <tr>
          <td align="right" width="20">
    Contact Person(in case of emergency):</td>
          <td >
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="cp" ></td>
      <td align="right">
    Tel. no:</td>
          <td >
    <input
     type="text" size="20" name="tel2" ></td></tr>


      <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Address:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="address"  size="50"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Reffered By:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="reff" size="31"></td>
          </tr>

        <tr>
         <td class="topHeadrow5" valign="top" width="200" colspan="5">
    <b><font size="4">
    Past Medical History:</font></b></td>
          </tr>

    <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Allergy:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="all" size="31"></td>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Previous illness:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="ill" size="31"></td>
          </tr>

        <tr>
         <td class="topHeadrow5" valign="top" width="100%" colspan="5">
    <b><font size="4">
    Heredo-Familial Diseases:</font></b></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Maternal:
         </td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="mat" size="20"></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Fraternal:
         </td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="frat" size="20"></td>
          </tr>

    <tr>
         <td class="topHeadrow5" valign="top" width="100%" colspan="5">
    <b><font size="4">
    Examination:</font></b></td>
          </tr>   
    <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Date / Time:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="datetime" size="31"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td valign="top" align="right" nowrap>
    Vital Signs:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="vs" size="31"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td align="center" nowrap>
    Complain PPE Findings:</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="ppe" size="31"></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
          <td align="center" nowrap>
    Plan / Management / FF-UP</td>
          <td valign="top" align="left">
    <input type="text" name="ffup" size="31"></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="90%"><input class="form-button" type="Submit" name="submit" value="Enter information"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <?
    }

    ?>
```

The result of the above code is on the screenshot above. I commented out the `include ('testinclude.php'). But once I include that file, all the data on the patient information is gone BUT the procedures column looks gone. I want both of them to show up.

When I include the testinclude.php. This is the result:

[image]

testinclude.php

```
<?

$id = '17';
//printf("<td align=left><font face=Verdana size=1 color=red>There are no Records</font></td>",$num); //prints number

$procedures = "SELECT * FROM incurredcharges WHERE patient_no = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($procedures ,$dbh2);


    if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1){


            $procedures = "SELECT
            `incurredcharges`.`procedure_no`,
  `c`.`procedure`

FROM
  incurredcharges
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `procedure`, `procedure_no` FROM `charges`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `confinement`, `procedure_no` FROM `confinement`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `service`, `procedure_no` FROM `ultrasound`
  ) c ON `incurredcharges`.`procedure_no` = c.`procedure_no`
WHERE `incurredcharges`.`patient_no` = '$id'";

            $result2 = mysql_query($procedures ,$dbh2);


            echo "<p><table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 bordercolor=#000000 width=100%>";
            echo "<tr align=top>
            <td class=topHeadrow5><b>Procedure #</b></td>
            <td class=topHeadrow5><b>Charge Incurred</b></td></tr>";


        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

                    echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row[0].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row[1].'</td>'; 
                        echo "</tr>";

        }
        echo '</table>';
        }
    else {

        echo "<p><table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 bordercolor=#000000 width=100%>";
        echo "<tr align=top>
        <td class=topHeadrow4><b>There are no Records</b></td></tr></table>";
        return false;
        }
?>
```

I already used the trick on connecting multiple databases. Every `mysql_query`, I specified what dtabase config it corresponds to. But it still doesnt work.

EDIT:

OK I just tried moving the include('testinclude.php') at the bottom. AND IT WORKED. It shows both the patient info and the procedures..

But in my official codes, it doesnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create `link` for each database and pass that link to query

```
 $link1 = mysql_select_db('invoices', $dbh1);
 $link2 = mysql_select_db('hmis', $dbh2);


 $sql1 = mysql_query($query1,$link1);
 $sql2 = mysql_query($query2,$link2);
```

Comment: Thats what I did. Every mysql_query I see, i add the corresponding database connection like, `$result = mysql_query($sql,$dbh1);`

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below code,

```
$dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
$dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 

mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2);

Then to query database 1, do this:

mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh1);

and for database 2:

mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh2);
```

Comment: I added pconnect on my two connections and its still the same

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Maybe something about the very long code wont make it work. But I tried on a simple code, it works. But on mine it doesnt. Please check out the code I posted. Every mysql_query, I specified the connecton just like that.

Answer (score 0):

While opening second MySql connection, you need to pass 5th argument as true.

Please refer **MySql** manual,

```
resource mysql_connect (string $server, string $username,   
string $password, bool $new_link = false )
```

**new_link**
If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned. The new_link parameter modifies this behavior and makes mysql_connect() always open a new link, even if mysql_connect() was called before with the same parameters. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored.

I hope this helps.